# Host volumes / environment variables not available during container build stage

Tags: docker, dokku

I have the following set up

```
Build options:
    --link dokku.postgres.xsacdb-database:dokku-postgres-xsacdb-database
    -v /storage/xsacdb/conf:/app/conf
    -v /storage/xsacdb/media:/app/media
Deploy options:
    --link dokku.postgres.xsacdb-database:dokku-postgres-xsacdb-database
    -v /storage/xsacdb/conf:/app/conf
    -v /storage/xsacdb/media:/app/media
Run options:
    --link dokku.postgres.xsacdb-database:dokku-postgres-xsacdb-database
    -v /storage/xsacdb/conf:/app/conf
    -v /storage/xsacdb/media:/app/media
```

However when pushing and triggering a build these directories are not accessible.

```
ls: cannot access /app/conf: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /app/media: No such file or directory
```

They are available once the container is built

```
dokku run xsacdb bash
$ ls /app/conf
files here!
```

My [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/wjdp/c19959534f6876214d33)

#### Edit

In addition the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable set my the postgres plugin is also not available at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker build does not accept those parameters http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/

dokku must just silently ignore them.

I believe the only way to provide data to the dokku build is to put the files in the git repo.